# Simulate click on external domain

Tags: php

**BASIS:**

I'm trying to create a web application where I can accept tickets and requests from multiple other external domains/URL's with a simple click of a button.

To accept a request/ticket you need to -as of now- enter the page's URL -> click a button/link to accept -> DONE!

This is doable for URL's where the "button" is either a link like `<a href='performAccept'>` or a form like `<form action='performAccept'>`.
Because then I can simply use `$html = get_content_of_url($url);`
And look for these `<a>` or `<form>` and copy the url of these tags.

Now to the question and the tricky part. Sometimes there are no links nor forms, and instead a `<input type='submit>` and it has no URL connected to it.

**QUESTION:**
Can I somehow enter a website which contains almost only of an `<input type='submit'>` and simulate a "click" as if I had the URL to the "click's" destination?

I would prefer to solve this using PHP. But Python is also an option.

Comment: every `<input type='submit'>` must be in a `<form action='performAccept'>` and you told that you can read `url` from `form action`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simulate a click. What you could do is:

POST the form with all the necessary fields via CURL.
Solid websites have CSRF tokens. So I guess you wont be able to do so easily.

Here is an example to it: [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)